# Control Where Pages Are Inserted

Tags: vba, pdf, adobe

I am using the below syntax to split a master pdf into multiple sub pdfs.  My issue is that the pages are inserted in reverse order, so instead of going 1, 2, 3, 4 the input goes 4, 3, 2, 1.

What would I need to change so that the order of pages in the new workbook goes 1, 2, 3 4?

```
    For i = 1 To PNum
        Set newPDF = CreateObject("AcroExch.pdDoc")
        newPDF.Create
        NewName = "R:" & i & ".pdf"
        newPDF.InsertPages -1, PDDoc, i, 4, 0
        newPDF.Save 1, NewName
        newPDF.Close
        Set newPDF = Nothing
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first parameter (-1) you are telling Acrobat to insert your new pages before page 1. Acrobat page numbers are zero based so the line should read...

```
newPDF.InsertPages newPDF.GetNumPages-1, PDDoc, i, 4, 0
```

... to insert new pages at the end of the new PDF document.

Comment: Minor tweak should be newPDF.GetNumPages and it works perfectly!

Comment: Yes - that's correct. I updated my answer. Sorry for any confusion. I was using the JavaScript property by mistake.